# How would I use jquery to add a line break when pressing enter in a html textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been looking all over Google, and found some interesting ways to do this, but none of them hide the `<br />`

I read that if I used `\n` it wouldn't show up, but it does show up in the text field. I can always have something in the textarea and `preg_replace` it with `<br />` later I suppose in my php that handles the form associated with the text area.

To clarify, I have a textarea that will need several line breaks to separate content. So I want a user to be able to press enter for a new line, and add a `<br />` at the end of each line. But I do not want the `<br />` or whatever I insert to replace later to be visible to the user.

A good example is Facebook. Facebook is very javascript heavy. So much that you need to press shift + enter in order to get a new line so the form doesn't submit. But when you enter text on two lines there is a line break inserted so the content displays on two lines and you never see the `<br />` or whatever they use inside of the form when writing your post.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using a `textarea` or `contentEditable`? This makes a _huge_ difference.

Comment: html textarea. I believe i wrote this in my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The default behaviour of a `<textarea>` **is** that enter inserts a newline, so I'm a bit confused. Are you taking the value and displaying it elsewhere?

Comment: Your assumptions don't match what I see when I use Facebook. I can press enter without the post submitting. It's different for comments I think. Also, the newline is represented as `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: /n was a type error on my part. Here is the thing. I am taking the value and displaying it elsewhere. In my textarea I can hit enter and it goes to the database and in the database the text is on separate lines. But there is no \n or br in the database because i have not specified for there to be. So when i print out the contents everything is on one line. my point about Facebook is that it does what i want. You hit enter, text is on a new line and you cant see the \n or br in the textarea but when the results are printed on the page things ar on their own line.

Comment: @faildistraction You'll need to replace the newlines in the string with `<br/>` tags. How you do that depends on where exactly you're displaying the value. If you're sending it to a database, then displaying it on the same or another page after reloading, then it would probably make sense to do that in your PHP code. If you're taking the value directly from the textarea and displaying it on the same page using JavaScript then `$('#your-textarea-id').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')` [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/BTDz7/).

Comment: @faildistraction To elaborate, the browser condenses any amount of whitespace (spaces, tabs, linebreaks, etc) in HTML into a single space, which is what you're seeing when you simply try to output the value as part of the page. If you were to inspect the source code for the page, however, I suspect you'd see that there are indeed line breaks in it.

Comment: The preferred method would be to take the value from my textarea and fix it up in my php before sending it off to the database. I'm strong in php just not javascript. I'm just unsure of how to insert some kind of indicator whether it is \n br or whatever into the textarea upon pressing enter without it being visible. That is where my problem lies.

Comment: it is already doing what you need. the \n is put in automatically by the textarea. you just cant see it because it is a hidden character. When you output the database contents use nl2br();

Comment: @faildistraction The preferred method would be to save the string as it's sent to the server in your database, and replace the `\n` with `<br/>` after reading back from the database to display in read-only format on the page. If you start messing about with it before you save it to your DB you may end up with headaches if/when you want to let them edit it again - you'd have to do the reverse conversion (and that may not necessarily be 100% reliable) when putting it back into a textarea.

Comment: Mike, you're maybe a minute too late. haha I just did that and it works great. Much better method than jquery in my opinion. Thanks everyone. i did learn a few things.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @faildistraction As I said originally, the default behaviour of a textarea is to insert a newline when the user presses the enter key. If that's *not* happening it's because you have custom JavaScript to modify that behaviour - if that's the case, identify that and post it in the question. You could probably modify it quite easily to only do the custom part if the enter key isn't pressed (allowing the user to do shift+enter for a newline in your textarea).

Comment: There is no custom js, Anthony. I just wasn't thinking everything through clearly. I answered the question guys. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I used the php nl2br function to convert \n to `<br />`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

I like this method because it doesn't require anything extra. Just wrap nlbr2() around my variable and that is it. Php is all ready adding the \n for me, just needed to convert it.

Comment: Remember: HTML4 = `<br>`, XHTML = `<br />`, HTML5 = `<br>`; use `nl2br($str, false);` if HTML5.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more of what the false is for?

Comment: No, my comment sais it clear enough, you could read up on the link you posted: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

use nl2br() before save the similar content.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

```
$content = nl2br($content);
```

and save.

Comment: I all ready answered the question with this as the answer, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I was preparing this and your answer appeared.

Comment: There`s 7 minutes difference between the answers, how long were you preparing `nl2br()` :D